# Casting year ToInt16 not working

Tags: c#, casting

I have a function that basically does:

```
internal static short GetPresentYear()
{
    return Convert.ToInt16(DateTime.Now.Year - 1);
}
```

Now when I try using the function, the debugger shows that I'm getting `0x07d9` instead of the year 2008...

What am I doing wrong here? How do I make it return 2008?

Thanks.

**Edit**: I know I can use `int` instead of `short` but the database is designed to store `smallint` and so I'm forced to use a `short`.

Comment: Is the Year on your computer 2009?

Comment: I don't see any problems at all, I copied and pasted your code exactly and it returns 2008 just fine for me.  It might have something to do with your display settings.  Have you tried writing it to console to see what it displays as?

Comment: Your code worked perfectly for me. One small point, naming something GetPresentYear and then returning year-1 is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Pete: There is more code but basically that is what is does... Returns the present academic year based on a few parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That does return 2008 for me. Is that your actual code?

For info, 0x07d9 is simply 2009 in hex. You can toggle this in the debugger by hovering over the value and checking / unchecking "Hexadecimal Display".

Comment: That was it. The hexadecimal display got all confusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you got `Hexadecimal Display` turned on in your output window?

Right click over the output window and it's an option on the context menu.

Answer (score 3):

Hexadecimal 0x07d9 is 2009 decimal, so everything is correct.

Right-click on the locals / watch window and un-check the hexadecimal setting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the debugger set to display hexa values? 0x07d9 is hexa for 2009. Go over the watch window, right click and check that 'hexadecimal display' is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

i got 2008. not 0x07d9(its [Hexadecimal Display](http://sa-action.blogspot.com/2007/09/hexadecimal-display.html))